# How can I write a route that forces to a single controller/action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to create a temporary website that basically locks it to display a single controller action.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Test",
  url: "Test/Index"
);
```

This is all I have in my RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method other than:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

When I load the page I get:

```
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{*url}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index"});
```

Forces all requests to the TestController with the method Index.